Questions regarding endian Byte swapping
I need to write a Python Program that asks for user data, stores them in a binary file and and sends them via socket in binary format to a device.
The data should be transfered in little endian byte order. The following questions arised:

I understand that .to_bytes() with byteorder='little' stores the data in RAM in little endian. What if I write these binary data later to a file, Will there be another endian swap in the file depending on the sys.byteorder of the computer?
What if I open the file with a hex editor, will I see the data how they are or will there be another byte swap when the editor reads the file?
If my program should work independently to the sys.byteorder of the computer what is the best strategy?

So far I saw that .to_bytes() swaps the bytes in memory.

No, writing to the files works in bytes. You only need to do the conversion when you create the byte string.

Thank you. So if I have some bytes in a byte array and I write them to a file, will there be a byte swapping depending on sys.byteorder?

Here's a quick little test I put together.
data = 123456
print(hex(data))
# 0x1e240 (these are the bytes I expect to be written)

data_bytes = data.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')
with open('datafile.log', 'bw') as datafile:
    datafile.write(data_bytes)

When I open datafile.log in a hex editor, this is what I see
40 E2 01 00

This tracks with little-endian byte order. Conversely, if we set byteorder='big', this is what you get
00 01 E2 40

Notice that this matches what we printed before!

Thank you. If I would do these 2 tests on two different machines where one has sys.byteorder little (like x86) and the other is big(like Solaris) what results should I get?

I did this test on a Windows (x86) machine and it appears to respect the byte order specified by to_bytes, given that when I specify 'big' the result is big-endian as expected. Conversely, if you want the file write to follow the system byte order, you could always just use something like data_bytes = data.to_bytes(4, byteorder=sys.byteorder)

Is it a good strategy to define a certain endian ie little and let the program always handle the data with this endian. Therefore if the current machine has little endian then just do nothing special in your code. If it has big endian then modify the code to have little endian?
